# Node.js - Download .docx file exported as html from onedrive using microsoftgraph api call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When making a call like this example [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client#getstream)

```
client
    .api('/me/drive/root/children/Doc.docx/content') 
    .getStream((err, downloadStream) => {
        let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('Mydoc.docx');  
        downloadStream.pipe(writeStream).on('error', console.log);
    });
```

It works as expected. What I want is to get the .docx file as html. Is there any way to download it in html format? Or do I have to save the file and then try to export it to html. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word Documents (.docx) do not use HTML, they use Office Open XML (OOXML). Technically they are a zipped package that contains several elements along with the raw OOXML of the document.

OneDrive itself does not provide any document conversion tools, it is just the cloud storage the document is stored in.

In order to convert a document from one format to another (OOXML to HTML for example), you'll need to use a 3rd party tool or service for that purpose. I'd suggest taking a look as [Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/). They offer a slew of file format conversion tools including one for [Word](https://www.aspose.com/products/words). I've had a number of developers report good results using their [Aspose Cloud](https://www.aspose.com/products/words/cloud) services as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I do not think that I can follow this suggestion but it gives me a really good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add the query parameter format=html to download in html format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format?view=odsp-graph-online) but [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610600/3573) you have to use the beta endpoint.