# Microsoft Graph - OneDrive API - Convert to jpg before download

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to access two OneDrive items. The first is a `.docx` and the second a `.tif`. I'd like to convert these to `.jpg` before downloading them.

When I run a request for the content...

```
// gets access to the service
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = await GetGraphServiceClient();

// get the item
DriveItem item = await graphServiceClient
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("xxx")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

// set up query params
List<Option> options = new List<Option>();
options.Add(new QueryOption("format", "jpg"));

// get content stream for item, converted to .jpg format
item.Content = await graphServiceClient
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("xxx")
    .Content.Request(options)
    .GetAsync();
```

This throws an `Unknown Error` Service Exception.

I thought it could have been a poorly formed request, but I can change that QueryOption format to `pdf` and it returns as you'd expect.

[Here is the documentation for converting prior to download, showing that these formats are both supported to convert to jpg.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format)

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here, why I can't retrieve a jpg but can retrieve a pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Graph v1.0 only supports [converting to `pdf`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format). The ability to convert to other formats is only supported by [the Beta endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_get_content_format).

Supported in [`/v1.0`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format):

- `format=pdf`

Supported in [`/beta`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format):

- `format=pdf`
- `format=html`
- `format=glb`
- `format=jpg`

Unfortunately, the [OneDrive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format) does not make a distinction between **production** and **beta** functionality. For this reason, I don't recommend relying on it as a primary source. It is simply to easy to get tripped up just like this.

In order to convert to `jpg`, you will need to use the Beta endpoint but setting the `BaseUrl` property to `"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"`. Just be sure and do this *only* for this scenario and not globally. The Beta endpoint is not stable enough for production so it should only be used for dev/test and "there *is* no other way" scenarios.

Comment: wow, so Microsoft really just lumped all documentation into one spot even though it won't function properly? Is there a better source to rely on when developing for a production environment?

Comment: I agree that it super confusing. It is a known issue at the moment so hopefully, it will get cleared up soon. The links in my answer all point to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/. The Graph documentation makes a hard distinction between v1.0 and Beta.

Comment: Hi, I am getting `invalidRequest` when I convert `.docx` to `jpg` using this url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/EEB943FDB895C20D!122/content?format=jpg, don't know why, if I remove format than it gives me content. Any idea?  this is the response I am getting`
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Bad Argument",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "791b3f88-fc88-489b-a2da-a9d891492c18",
            "date": "2019-07-17T12:37:52"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: It doesn't work even on the beta endpoint for converting heic photos to jpg (as of today). I get a 400 error.